# String from file containing line breaks are not set in TextArea

Tags: java, textarea, vaadin

I read a normal text file with the following term:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(file.toPath())) // The function Files.readAllLines reads the file using standard UTF-8 encoding
    {
      sb.append(line);
    }
    return sb.toString();
```

The content of the file could be as follows:

```
This is a test text\nline break before\n\nantoher line break
```

Now my problem is, if I set this text into a TextArea, the text get just printed out as is:

```
This is a test text\nline break before\n\nantoher line break
```

Just if I set the text the following way:

```
textArea.setValue("This is a test text\nline break before\n\nantoher line break");
```

the line breaks are printed out.

What can I do the preserver the "\n" line breaks while reading a string from a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're losing the line breaks as a result of `readAllLines`.  You can manually add the line break in the append call.  You may or may not want to add one to the last line.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(file.toPath())) // The function Files.readAllLines reads the file using standard UTF-8 encoding
{
  sb.append(line).append('\n');
}
return sb.toString();
```